# Problem with installing GNOME Shell: unmet dependencies

Tags: 11.10, installation, gnome, dependencies

When I tried to install GNOME Shell (using Ubuntu Software Center) this error showed up.

[image: Error message]

The message says:

> **Package dependencies cannot be resolved**
>
> This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

Here the dependencies:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

gnome-shell: Depends: libpulse-mainloop-glib0 (>= 1:0.99.1) but 1:1.0-0ubuntu3 is to be installed
             Depends: libpulse0 (>= 1:0.99.1) but 1:1.0-0ubuntu3 is to be installed
             Depends: libxfixes3 (>= 1:5.0) but 1:5.0-4 is to be installed
```

So can you help me install GNOME Shell?

Comment: are you installing the 'gnome-shell' package using the Software Center? If not, can you try that?

Comment: Although it may not initially look like it, you can scroll that error message's details down. Exactly what dependencies is it complaining about? Alternatively, if it is a lot to write, you can try running `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell` in a terminal and paste the output in an edit, or use [pastebin.ubuntu.com](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: with terminal I wrote that command ,but it printed an error says 

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-shell : Depends: gnome-icon-theme-full but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: gnome-session-fallback but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I wrote sudo apt-get install gnome-icon-theme-full but with another error :
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-icon-theme-full : Depends: gnome-icon-theme (= 3.2.0-0ubuntu1) but 3.2.0-0ubuntu2 is to be installed.

Comment: Have you tried running updates lately? If that returns an error, it is possible you might need to fix your package dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem with gnome-session-fallback instalation.
The problem seems to be because you try to install something that depends on old versions of

> libpulse-mainloop-glib0,
>   libpulse0 and
>   libxfixes3

.
Try to uninstall those three and then install the gnome shell. The dependencies should get installed in older versions as a result.

Comment: The problem is that removing these breaks Unity, Cinnamon, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error, and I compared the package versions in a fresh install with those of the mirror and noticed a discrepancy.

Turns out that in my default Oneiric install, updates are not enabled by default.

To fix this,

1. Open the **Software Sources** application.
2. Go to the **Updates** tab and enable *oneiric-security* and *oneiric-updates*.
3. Open a terminal window and run `sudo apt-get update`.

Now you will be able to install `gnome-shell` and all its dependencies without problems.

At least that fixed the exact same error message that I got.

Answer (score 0):

try to install from terminal

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

if any dependency is missing , it will be displayed too, install them too.
after this you might be good to go.